# Method of images and induced charge

Tags: electrostatics, potential, potential-energy, conductors, method-of-images

I've read the section in *Introduction to Electrodynamics* by Griffiths over and over and I still don't understand the concept of the method of images. This problem builds on the concept of using an image charge inside a spherical conducting shell (neutral).

My confusion arises from a number of things.

1. Why do we even need to pretend to have a charge inside the conducting shell?
2. How can I geometrically perceive the concept of potential? Currently, I imagine putting a tack on a board. Then, I loop one end of a rubber band to the tack and begin to pull the rubber band to the left. As I move farther and farther to the left, the tension in the rubber band grows to infinity. If I were to let go, the rubber band would fly towards the right with an energy related to the amount of tension in the band just before release. I imagine this when moving a charge closer to another charge. As I move one charge closer and closer to another one, the amount of energy that the charge *will* have once released becomes greater and greater. This is my understanding of potential. Is this correct?
3. What does adding another charge do in the problem below?

> For a grounded sphere ($V=0$) a single image charge is sufficient. But with the addition of a second image charge, the same basic model will handle the case of a sphere at any potential $V_0$ (relative to infinity). What charge should you use, and where should you put it? Find the force of attraction between a point charge $q$ and a *neutral* conducting sphere.

**Update:** I solved for the potential on the outside of the sphere and on the surface. If I'm wrong, please feel free to help me understand better.

Potential outside the sphere:

$V=\displaystyle\frac{kq}{R}$ when $r>R$.

Potential on the surface:

$V=\displaystyle\frac{kq}{R} + kq(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{R})$ when $r<R$.

Comment: The method of images allows you to write down a solution to the boundary value problem defined by Laplace's equation + boundary conditions. Due to the uniqueness theorem, this solution is unique. However, it is in principle always possible to solve an image problem using a conventional "series solution" as explained in Chapter 3 of Griffiths (in the 4th edition, this chapter is just called "Potentials").

Comment: We don't "pretend". The solution (if found using the series method for instance) looks exactly like that with an image inside. That's the point. The cleverness lies in the fact that you can (often, not always) reduce a lot of work by an intelligent guess, and the fact that there is a uniqueness theorem means the solution you found to Laplace's equation -- if it satisfies the boundary conditions -- is indeed the correct solution.

Comment: Your rubber band example pertains to storage of potential energy (or more precisely, elastic potential energy) in a stretched rubber band. If the elastic force is conservative (i.e. the work done by this force in stretching the band from position A to position B is independent of the "path" taken in going from A to B), then the force is described by a potential, and hence potential energy is a well defined concept.

Comment: The situation with electrostatics is a bit different. First of all, if the two charges are of the same polarity, they will repel each other more and more as they are brought closer. This will in fact correspond to greater energy of the two-charge configuration. But if the polarities are different, the force between the charges is attractive and as the charges approach each other, the energy will reduce. In either case, a potential is well defined because electrostatic electric fields are conservative: the line integral of the electric field around any *closed* path is zero.

Comment: Hint for the final problem you ask: forgetting about images, what is the potential outside a spherical cavity (of radius $R$) which contains a charge $q$ somewhere inside, measured at a point at a distance $r$ ($r \geq R$) from the center of the cavity? What is the potential at $r = R$ (i.e. at the surface of the sphere)?

Comment: @leastaction I think it would be $V=\frac{kq}{4\pi R}$

Comment: Yes, the point is that a physical point charge anywhere inside the cavity will appear (by Gauss's Law) as a point charge at the center of the cavity for points outside the cavity. To raise the potential to $V_0$ in your problem, you will need to place a second charge at the center of the sphere with a value determined by $V_0 = kq/(4\pi R)$.

Comment: @leastaction I think it would be $V=\frac{kq}{R}$ when $r>R$. And it would be $V=\frac{kq}{R} + kq(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{R})$ when $r<R$.

Comment: Sorry, ignore the first one. I made a mistake.

Comment: How are you reasoning this? (I suggest editing your original post to include your working, so as to receive proper help.)

Comment: The surface of the sphere is an equipotential. But why do you expect the potential to stay constant for $r > R$? That is incorrect. As $r \rightarrow \infty$, you should have $V \rightarrow 0$, shouldn't you?

Comment: The equation for potential is $V=- \oint E \cdot dl$. For $r>R$, I used infinity as my reference point and $R$ as my upper bound. However, for the surface, I found the potential just outside the sphere and the potential inside the sphere. The book does an example in a similar way.

Comment: @leastaction Ohhhhh yes of course. Ok so then it's just $V=kq/r$. Then, should this single equation describe the potential at all points from the surface to infinity?

Comment: @leastaction hold on just one second, my mind has been blown. You're saying that the electric field coming from the charge inside stops at the wall of the sphere, but the potential stays the same as $r: (R, \infty)$?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Let me correct it by answering it in a few minutes. I'm almost done.

Comment: See Example 2.10 of Griffiths (4th edition, pages 100-101) for what happens in the case of a point charge inside a cavity carved in a conducting body. I'm traveling now, so its a bit difficult to type the whole answer out. Until I can, have a look at this example. Does it help?

Comment: Now, I suggest you remove your "Update:..." and whatever follows it, to make it less misleading for anyone who stumbles upon this question.

Answer (score 1):

You do know where $\nabla$$^2$V = -$\rho$/$\epsilon$$_0$ comes from. it comes directly from the divergence of the electric field and from the relation E = -$\nabla$V. There is a proof in Griffiths which shows why the solution of V is unique, if at all the boundaries of the system the potential is known, and the charge within the system remains the same. Given the uniqueness of this system, if one can intuitively guess a situation in which these situations hold, then ANY problem having the same initial conditions will have the same solution for potential. That is the basic idea behind image charge. To reduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you understand how to solve the problem of finding the potential outside a conducting sphere of radius $R$ (held at $V = 0$) when a point charge $q$ is placed at some distance $a$ outside the sphere ($a > R$), using the method of images (placing an image charge $q'$). To be sure, this is Example 3.2 in the textbook by Griffiths.

The problem you have posed asks you what you must do to solve this problem when the conducting sphere is held at a potential $V = V_0$. The answer is that you place a point charge $q''$ at the *center*: doing so keeps the sphere an equipotential, but just raises the potential at the surface to $V_0$ if

$$q'' = \frac{V_0 R}{k}$$

($k = 1/(4\pi\epsilon_0)$ in the notation you used in the comments.)

For the sphere to stay neutral, the *two* image charges $q'$ and $q''$ must add up to zero:

$$q' + q'' = 0$$

Then the force on external charge $q$ (which is the physical charge, in the region where you're effectively solving Laplace equation if you like) is due to $q'$ and $q''$ and is given by

$$F = kq\left[\frac{q''}{a^2} + \frac{q'}{\left(a - (R^2/a)\right)^2}\right]$$

---

Note that what you have done is solve Laplace equation in the region **outside** the spherical cavity (where the physical charge $q$ is placed). You **cannot** ask (in the above problem) what the potential or field inside the cavity are.

---

What you asked in the comments was therefore a different problem: consider a grounded conducing spherical cavity of radius $R$, with a charge $q$ placed somewhere *inside* it. What is the electric field and potential inside? Note that this is a different problem and should not be confused with the image problem above because for this problem you will effectively solve the Laplace equation *inside* the sphere. For more on this problem, see Problem 2.2 in http://users-phys.au.dk/thostrup/pdf/chapter2.pdf.

I will edit this answer to resolve any outstanding doubts/concerns you might have.

Comment: Why can't I ask what the field and the potential are inside the sphere? Is it because there are only ''fake'' charges inside?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Using the method of images, you cannot find what the potential inside is, as you're solving the equation in the complement of the space where the image is. You can argue that one can write the most general solution to the Laplace equation inside the sphere and outside the sphere, match them at the surface (since $V$ is continuous) and impose the condition that the tangential component of the electric field at the conductor's surface vanishes. This would determine $V(r)$ for both regions. See the comment in Griffiths's book at the bottom of Example 3.2 on page 128.

Comment: And see section 3.3 of Griffiths for a variety of problems where you solve Laplace equation in different regions through a series solution and patch up the descriptions in different regions using boundary conditions. This method (although more general) is more tedious but is often the only way out when writing the Green function for the arrangement isn't obvious from the method of images.

Comment: Also, what does it mean to say that the sphere is ''held at a potential $V_0$? Does it mean that you've placed it in a specific location where the potential is a certain value $V_0$?

Comment: Holding the sphere at a certain value $V_0$ means that the (conducting) sphere has been connected to a battery that keeps at a fixed potential $V_0$. This has nothing to do with where the sphere is: it could be anywhere. This just says that $V(r = R) = V_0$ always. It is a boundary condition on the potential on the surface. The caveat is that the source/sink (battery) which maintains this must source or sink any amount of charge to maintain the equipotential nature of the surface of the sphere.

Comment: Isnt the field inside a conductor always zero? Why trying to.use laplace equation and make things more complicated?

Comment: @lalala Please don’t resurrect an old thread and add a random comment. Second, please read the entire discussion prior to adding a new comment (and do the latter only if you have something completely new to add to such an old thread).

Comment: What is wrong with resurrection? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125965/is-bumping-old-questions-allowed it seems actually to be encouraged. Comment is not random, i read the thread completely (of course smtgh might have slipped my attention here). My first comment is refering to 21.9.16 0:41 to make things clearer. Also it seems that tge field is zero inside a conductor is smtgh completely new in this thread.

Comment: @lalala Please feel free to add an answer -- my answer was not accepted :-). In response to your objection, the OP asked a series of questions in the comments and also the objective was to explain some aspects of the method of images (which is a method to solve the Laplace equation). By the way, I still think the OP's question was satisfactorily answered 2 years ago. Best wishes :-) [I will cease to comment any further on this old thread. You are welcome to post an answer.]

Comment: @leastaction i have understood your method , likewise how to solve for force between two conducting spheres having charges q1 and q2? distance between them d and radius r1 ,r2